# Create Outlook MailItem and save as draft for other user

Tags: c#, vb.net, outlook, outlook-2010

I'm trying to create a mailitem and save it in the Drafts folder for an other user. I can create the draft but it only saves to my own draft folder, not for the other user. I have enough rights on the mailbox of the other user.

This is my test code so far:

```
        Dim omApp As New Outlook.Application

        Dim omNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace = omApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

        Dim omUser As Outlook.Recipient = omNamespace.CreateRecipient("otheruser@mail.com")
        omUser.Resolve()
        If Not omUser.Resolved Then
            MsgBox("Could not login.")
        End If

        Dim omDrafts As Outlook.MAPIFolder = omNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(omUser, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts)
        Dim omMailItem As Outlook.MailItem = CType(omDrafts.Items.Add, Outlook.MailItem)

        With omMailItem
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "otheruser@mail.com"
            .To = "bill@gates.com"
            .Subject = "Test"
            .Body = "Test email"
            .Save()
        End With
```

What am I doing wrong?

The code has to work for all Outlook versions from 2003 to 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've solved it myself. After the "Save" I add a "Move" to move it from my Drafts folder to the user's shared folder. So the code will be:

```
Dim omApp As New Outlook.Application

    Dim omNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace = omApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim omUser As Outlook.Recipient = omNamespace.CreateRecipient("otheruser@mail.com")
    omUser.Resolve()
    If Not omUser.Resolved Then
        MsgBox("Could not login.")
    End If

    Dim omDrafts As Outlook.MAPIFolder = omNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(omUser, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts)
    Dim omMailItem As Outlook.MailItem = CType(omDrafts.Items.Add, Outlook.MailItem)

    With omMailItem
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "otheruser@mail.com"
        .To = "bill@gates.com"
        .Subject = "Test"
        .Body = "Test email"
        .Save()

        .Move(omDrafts)

    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

GetDefaultFolder always defaults to your local default Drafts folder. Check out the [GetSharedDefaultFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220116%28v=office.11%29.aspx) method.

You must pass a Recipient object to this method -- you already have `omUser` for that. You must also pass the folder type, which should be `Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts`

Comment: You're right. I've submitted the wrong code; I've corrected that now. That doesn't solve my problem, though.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with C#, but could you be more specific about what is happening? Are you seeing an error msg? Also note that the other user has to delegate access to that folder to you.

Comment: No error. It just ignores the supplied folder and saves the mailitem in the Drafts folder of my own account (under which the code is running). Btw: if you should know the answer in an other language, then that's no problem for me.

Comment: Sorry I can't be more help here. I don't see why the code isn't working, other than not having delegate access to that folder. Or maybe I have the folder constant wrong.